# Why won't it delete the previous labels after having added more labels?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have recently been playing with tkinter (specifically buttons and labels) and so far I have created some simple code which displays a label, then using a button the label is removed, and through another button the label is brought back.

However, if I display two labels, only the most recent label can be removed, and I cannot find a way to remove the previous label. Here is the code so you can try it and look at the problem yourself:

```
import tkinter as tk

top = tk.Tk()

def on_click():
    global label
    label.after(10, label.destroy())

def restore():
    global label
    label = tk.Label (top, text = "INCOMING")
    label.pack(pady = 20)

tk.Button(top, text = "Delete?", command=on_click).pack()
tk.Button(top, text = "Restore?", command=restore).pack()

label = tk.Label(top, text = "TACTICAL NUKE")
label.pack(pady = 20)

top.mainloop()
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You're calling `.destroy()` only on one (global) `label`, why do you expect multiple labels to be  removed?

Answer (score 0):

The variable `label` is overwritten with a reference to the last label that is inserted. Therefore, you lose the references to the previous labels. You need to keep them somewhere in your program.

A good way to keep multiple related values in Python is to use a list. (Read about lists [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).)

In this case you can use a list to implement a data structure called "stack", where you add values to the end (by using the `append` method of the list) and remove them from the end (by using the `pop` method).

The simplest possible change to make this work would be to replace the global variable `label` by a global variable `labels` which is a list that contains references to labels.

```
import tkinter as tk

top = tk.Tk()

def on_click():
    label = labels.pop()
    label.after(10, label.destroy())

def restore():
    label = tk.Label (top, text = "INCOMING")
    label.pack(pady = 20)
    labels.append(label)

tk.Button(top, text = "Delete?", command=on_click).pack()
tk.Button(top, text = "Restore?", command=restore).pack()

label = tk.Label(top, text = "TACTICAL NUKE")
label.pack(pady = 20)
labels = [label]

top.mainloop()
```

Now you need to consider what should happen after the original label has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

> and I cannot find a way to remove the previous label.

You cannot put the `Label` widget in `restore()` function. Doing so, will create more duplicate label widgets evey time you click.

Renamed `label` to `incoming_label` to prevent other widget

Put the `Label` widget outside of the function.

Then use `incoming_label.configure()` inside `restore()` function.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk

top = tk.Tk()

def on_click():
    global label
    label.after(10, label.destroy())

def restore():
     incoming_label.configure(text = "INCOMING")
     
     
tk.Button(top, text = "Delete?", command=on_click).pack()
tk.Button(top, text = "Restore?", command=restore).pack()

incoming_label = tk.Label (top)
incoming_label.pack(pady = 20)

label = tk.Label(top, text = "TACTICAL NUKE")
label.pack(pady = 20)

top.mainloop()
```

The script will prevent duplicate `Label` widget(s)